# Android studio random item always same values

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-studio, kotlin

I am codding a quiz application in android studio. But when i run the app, I see always same values. I tried more times. But it doesn't work. (I am using **Kotlin** Language)

My code:

```
fun  two_click(view: View)
{
    val list1 = mutableListOf<String>("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
    var list2 = mutableListOf<String>()
    var random_item : String? = null
    while(true)
    {
        random_item = list1.random().toString()
        if(list2.contains(random_item))
        {
            continue
        }
        else
        {
            list2.add(random_item)
        }

        if(list2.size == 4)
        {
            break
        }
    }
    println(list2)
}
```

When I run the app, my outputs always same:

[image: Go outputs]

I am trying random item when i run the app without same outputs. How can i fix this code ?

Comment: You are iterating through the whole list before exiting the loop instead of picking just one item and breaking. And each time you call this function you are starting over from scratch because all the variables are local to the function. Nothing will be remembered between calls to the function.

Comment: Thanks for answer but already i want to 4 item from list1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am not sure that I understood your goals correctly but...*

The random numbers generator is pseudo-random. It means that for each start of the program it will generate the same values. To fix that, you can use seed, based on which numbers will be generated.

```
val rand = Random(1) // it will be your seed
random_item = list1.random(rand).toString()
```

If you always want to provide different outputs and therefore different seeds, you can create seed like this

```
val rand = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
```